# Magento order email

Tags: magento

Hi I use magento for my e-commerce. I created order email templates in adminstration. It works fine, but in my templates I have payment methods How Can I add some thing or edit it?. I dont have it in my admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the title from 'payment method' go to Admin -> Transaction Email -> import or update both Order template

The templates file is located at frontend/base/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml (without knowing the exact changes it's hard to advise any further)